# Only suggest executables and not directories when typing ./ (dot-slash) in zsh

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

Here's an example snippet from my current zsh session:

```
llama@llama:...Code/cpp/KingOfTheCode$ make
clang++ -std=c++11 -Iinclude src/*.cpp kothsrc/*.cpp -pthread -o KingOfTheCode
llama@llama:...Code/cpp/KingOfTheCode$ ./
Completing executable file or directory
include/        KingOfTheCode*  kothsrc/        src/
```

(I typed a `.`, a `/`, and then a <kbd>Tab</kbd> character for autocompletion.)

Why does zsh suggest directories when I type `./<tab>`? I clearly want to execute a file, and if I wanted to execute something in a subdirectory the `./` part would be useless.

How can I prevent this annoying behavior from occurring? Just to be clear, my desired behavior is that autocompletion for `./<...>` excludes directories and only looks for executable files.

Comment: I thought the `./` would just refer to the current directory. Why would a sub-directory be useless then?

Comment: @NobuGames When I type `./`, it's usually because I want to execute something in the current directory (for example, `./something.py`). If I wanted to execute, say, `foo/bar/baz/something.py`, the `./` would be useless because it's implied.

Comment: I guess it would be fine if `setout autocd` is in effect, so we can type `./`, `Tab`, `Tab`... for `cd`ing subdirectory. But I personally am not using `autocd` a lot anyway.

Comment: Ugh… I'm very sorry for above my comment, `s/setout/setopt/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that there is [`compinit`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-compinit) somewhere in the `~/.zshrc`.

You could limit the completion results by `zstyle`like this:

```sh
zstyle -e ':completion::complete:-command-::executables' ignored-patterns '
  [[ "$PREFIX" == ./* ]] && { reply=(./*(/)) }
'
```

This adds the [`ignored-patterns`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-ignored_002dpatterns_002c-completion-style) zstyle entries when typing `./<...>` then hitting the <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Abobe `./*(/)` part indicates directories in the current directory. As a result, any subdirectories will be removed from completion results when completing the “executable file or directory”.

If you want to reinstate completion results without `ignored-patterns` effects if there are no matching completions, you could add the [`_ignored`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fignored) completer:

```sh
# this is same as the zsh default behavior though.
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _ignored
```

It should complete the ignored subdirectories in this case with typing `./ko`<kbd>Tab</kbd> ⇒ `./koshsrc/`.

---

**Update:** Mon, 29 Dec 2014 21:30:37 +0900 (Thank you for your suggestion, @Francisco)
Teach to skip directories of which namestring has some spaces in it.

```sh
zstyle -e ':completion::complete:-command-::executables' ignored-patterns '
  [[ "$PREFIX" == ./* ]] && {
    local -a tmp; set -A tmp ./*(/)
    : ${(A)tmp::=${tmp// /\\ }}
    reply=(${(j:|:)tmp})
  }
'
```

Comment: Why did this answer get a down vote? It works. (Ok, it does not work for directories with a space in it, but other than that it 'works for me').

Comment: I've updated to try to handle spaces correctly. Thank you very much for your report, @Francisco!